# Will this function be evaluated lazily?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to understand if the following function will be evaluated lazily.

My understanding is "head" will take the first item from a list. Will optimalTests just evaluate the first item in [Test] or will all Tests in [Test] be created before head is subsequently called?

```
optimalTests :: State -> [Test]

--implementation here

getAnyTest :: State -> Test

getAnyTest s = head(optimalTests s)
```

Comment: `getAnyTest s = head (optimalTests s)` or `getAnyTest = head . optimalTests`.

Comment: There's no real way to answer this question (correctly) without knowing how `optimalTests` is defined. It may produce tests lazily, or it may not.

Comment: What we *can* say is that `head` will only scrutinize the first constructor of the list, regardless of what `optimalTests` does first.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend messing about with the `:print` and `:sprint` commands in `ghci` to see lazy evaluation in action. For example:

```
Prelude> let names = ["Joe", "Jen", "Anne"]
Prelude> let hellos = map ((++) "Hello ") names
Prelude> head hellos
"Hello Joe"
Prelude> :sprint hellos
hellos = "Hello Joe" : _
Prelude> length hellos
3
Prelude> :sprint hellos
hellos = ["Hello Joe",_,_]
Prelude> last hellos
"Hello Anne"
Prelude> :sprint hellos
hellos = ["Hello Joe",_,"Hello Anne"]
```

That way you can see how the list is progressively evaluated as you call different functions on it. The `_` represents an unevaluated thunk.

You could load your code into `ghci` and experiment in a similar way. Just make sure you assign things to variables or they will be evaluated by the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it will only create the first value, nothing else...

You could test this by returning an array that crashes on the second element.

```
optimalTests _ = [aValidValue, error "crash!"]
```

If the program doesn't crash (it won't), that means it never tried to evaluate the second item.

Comment: Also, just to be clear....  `getAnyTest` itself is also defined lazily, so it won't even evaluate the first item unless you call `getAnyTest` in the main IO action.

Comment: You're just speculating on how `optimalTests` is structured. It could actually realize all the tests before yielding any.